# My Custom Skin pack won't import or showup

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying to create a custom skinpack for about 2 days now but every time I go to import it it always does "Failed to import 'Dream Smp Skin Pack' duplicate pack detected. My skins.json code is

```
{
  "geometry": "skinpacks/skins.json",
  "skins": [
    {
      "localization_name": "BBH",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "BBH.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "BBHE",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "BBH Egg.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "BossQuackity"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Boss Quackity.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "CharileSlimecicle"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Charile Slimecicle.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "DDream"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Detailed Dream.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "DGirlTechnoblade"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Detailed Girl Technoblade.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "Dream"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Dream.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "Drista"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Drista.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "GeorgeNotFound"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "GeorgeNotFound.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "Ghostbur"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Ghostbur.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "Ghostburwithhorns"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Ghostbur with Horns.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "GTechnoblade"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Girl Technoblade.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "GTommyinit"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Girl Tommyinit.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
    "localization_name": "GTubbobeetrousers"
    "geometry": "geometry.humaniod.custom",
    "texture": "Girl Tubbo w/ Bee Trousers.png"
    "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "KarlJacobs",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Karl Jacobs.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "MexicanDream",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Mexican Dream.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "RainbowDream",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Rainbow Dream.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "Revivebur",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Revivebur.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "Sapnap",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Sapnap.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "Skeppy",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Skeppy.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "SkeppyE",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Skeppy Egg.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "Technoblade",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Technoblade.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "Tommyinit",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Tommyinit.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "Tubbow/beetrousers",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Tubbo w/ Bee Trousers.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "Ranboo",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Ranboo.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "GRanboo",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Girl Ranboo.png",
      "type": "free"
    },
    {
      "localization_name": "DRanboo",
      "geometry": "geometry.humanoid.custom",
      "texture": "Detailed Ranboo.png",
      "type": "free"
    }
  ],
  "serialize_name": "Dream Smp Skin Pack",
  "localization_name": "mbsp"
}
```

My manifest.json code is

```
{
    "format_version": 1,
    "header": {
        "name": "Dream Smp Skin Pack",
        "uuid": "b853a00e-4e1c-4987-b954-86d841be2b37",
        "version": [
            1,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "modules": [
        {
            "type": "skin_pack",
            "uuid": "56f3ec43-224e-4c21-8af9-d26d86c62353",
            "version": [
                1,
                0,
                0
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and my en_US.lang code is

```
skin.mbsp.BBH=BBH
skin.mbsp.BBHE=BBH Egg
skin.mbsp.BossQuackity=Boss Quackity
skin.mbsp.CharlieSlimecicle=Charlie Slimecicle
skin.mbsp.DDream=Detailed Dream
skin.mbsp.DGirlTechnoblade=Detailed Genderbent Technoblade
skin.mbsp.Dream=Dream
skin.mbsp.Drista=Drista
skin.mbsp.GeorgeNotFound=GeorgeNotFound
skin.mbsp.Ghostbur=Ghostbur
skin.mbsp.Ghostburwithhorns=Ghostbur with Horns
skin.mbsp.GTechnoblade=Genderbent Technoblade
skin.mbsp.GTommyinit=Genderbent Tommyinit
skin.mbsp.GTubbobeetrousers=Genderbent Tubbo w/ Bee Trousers
skin.mbsp.KarlJacobs=Karl Jacobs
skin.mbsp.MexicanDream=Mexican Dream
skin.mbsp.RainbowDream=Rainbow Dream
skin.mbsp.Revivebur=Revivebur
skin.mbsp.Sapnap=Sapnap
skin.mbsp.Skeppy=Skeppy
skin.mbsp.SkeppyE=Skeppy Egg
skin.mbsp.Technoblade=Technoblade
skin.mbsp.Tommyinit=Tommyinit
skin.mbsp.Tubbow/beetrousers=Tubbo w/ Bee Trousers
skin.mbsp.Ranboo=Ranboo
skin.mbsp.GRanboo=Genderbent Ranboo
skin.mbsp.DRanboo=Detailed Ranboo
skinpack.mbsp=Dream Smp Skin Pack
```

Sorry if it's a lot.